# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make the weather app in React JS , but when I run the program I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')". Below is part of the code:

```
 return (
 <div className={(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? ((weather.main.temp > 16 ) ? 
 'app warm':'app'):'app'}>
   <main>

   <div className="search-box">

     <input type='text' 
      className='search-bar' 
      placeholder='Search ...'
      onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
      value={query}
      onKeyPress={search}
      />
    </div>
    
    {(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? (
     <div>
      <div className='location-box'>
      <div className='location'>{weather.name}, {weather.sys.country}</div>
      <div className='date'>
        {dateBuilder(new Date())}
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className='weather-box'>
      <div className='temp'>
      {Math.round(weather.main.temp)}
      </div>
      <div className='weather'>
      {weather.weather[0].main}
      </div>
    
      </div>
     </div>
    ): (' ')}
  </main>
   </div>
  );
  }
```

Comment: which react js version are you using

Comment: Can you include the entire component? we need to know how you define and load your state variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weather` is undefined at some point. Since you are only checking if `weather.main` is undefined or not, at some point your code tries to read field `main` of `undefined`.

One solution may be conditional chaining. Try changing

```
(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? ...
```

to

```
weather?.main && (...
```

#### Full code

```
return (
 <div className={`app ${weather?.main?.temp > 16 ? 'app warm':''}`}>
   <main>

   <div className="search-box">

     <input type='text' 
      className='search-bar' 
      placeholder='Search ...'
      onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
      value={query}
      onKeyPress={search}
      />
    </div>
    
    {weather?.main && (
     <div>
      <div className='location-box'>
      <div className='location'>{weather.name}, {weather.sys.country}</div>
      <div className='date'>
        {dateBuilder(new Date())}
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className='weather-box'>
      <div className='temp'>
      {Math.round(weather.main.temp)}
      </div>
      <div className='weather'>
      {weather.weather[0].main}
      </div>
    
      </div>
     </div>
    ): (' ')}
  </main>
   </div>
  );
  }
```